# Find the values for n0 and the constant factor c such that f(n) = n log n is Ω(n)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I was recently introduced to big O and big Omega, as well as big theta. I know that big O is the worse case scenario in terms of runtime, big Omega is the best case scenario, and big theta is in between. However, I'm still confused on how I would use it mathematically to prove that n log n = Ω(n). Also, I get that n0 is the lowest possible number for the equation to work, but where does the constant factor c come in? Any advice and help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: IMO this question belongs to https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the definition of big-O, but struggle with the definition of big-Ω, you can use [Knuth's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of big-Ω to turn it around for you:

*f(n) = Ω(n) <=> n = O(f(n))*

Thus, if you can prove that *n = O(n logn)*, you have proven your original problem.

If you are looking to understand the c and n0 defnition of big-Ω, I'm sure there are examples online. As already noted, see [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com) and [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the definition of big-Ω,

we can say if the function *f(n)* is having growth rate faster than that of *g(n)* , f(n) = Ω(g(n))

Here n log n always grows faster than n
Hence, n log n = Ω(n).